# How to define a auto-update $DATE variable in bash?

Tags: bash

When I backup a file, I add a timestamp to it.

For example:

```
$ DATE=$(date +%F)
$ cp file{,.$DATE.bk}
$ ls
file  file.2012-06-20.bk
```

There is a bash variable `RANDOM`, every time I echo it, it gives me different values:

```
$ echo $RANDOM
20511
$ echo $RANDOM
12577
$ echo $RANDOM
32433
```

How can I define such kind of a variable `DATE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the bash source code in order to provide it. But make sure you know what format everyone wants their date in before doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You could hold the command statement and evaluate it on use.

```
$ DATE="date +%F"
$ echo $DATE
date +%F
$ echo `$DATE`
2012-06-20
```

Answer (score 3):

You are attacking the problem from the wrong angle.  Write a script which creates a backup.

```
#!/bin/sh
for f; do
    cp "$f" "$f.$(date +%F).bk"
done
```

This is simple enough to go as a function in your `.profile` if you don't want to litter your `$HOME/bin` with basically a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Bash has no such feature. You should use ksh93's *discipline functions* if you need getters/setters/properties, and generally anything that's going to require OO.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

function DATE.get {
    .sh.value=$(printf '%(%F)T')
}

cp file{,".${DATE}.bk"}
```

I'm not aware of any other shell that can do this except perhaps through their respective loadable extension interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a variable that updates automatically that contains the number of seconds since the shell started.

You can set the value and it will update starting with that base. The disadvantage is that it uses an epoch seconds timestamp format. You can use `date` to convert it back.

Here's a demo:

```
$ bash
$ echo "$SECONDS"
5
$ date +%s; SECONDS=$(date +%s); echo "$SECONDS"
1340191083
1340191083
$ sleep 10
$ date +%s; echo "$SECONDS"
1340191097
1340191097
$ date -d "@$SECONDS"
Wed Jun 20 06:18:24 CDT 2012
$ date -d "@$SECONDS" +%F
2012-06-20
```

The extra seconds are because of the startup time of Bash and the time it takes to type the commands.

```
$ bash -c 'echo $SECONDS'
0
```