# linux bash script: set date/time variable to auto-update (for inclusion in file names)

Tags: bash, variables, date, time, auto-update

Essentially, I have a standard format for file naming conventions.  It breaks down to this:

```
target_dateUTC_timeUTC_tool
```

So, for instance, if I run tcpdump on a target of 'foo', then the file would be `foo_dateUTC_timeUTC_tcpdump`.  Simple enough, but a pain for everyone to constantly (and consistently) enter... so I've tried to create a bash script which sets system variables like so:

```
FILENAME=$TARGET\_$UTCTIME\_$TOOL
```

Then, I can just call the variable at runtime, like so:

```
tcpdump -w $FILENAME.lpc
```

All of this works like a champ.  I've got a menu-driven .sh which gives the user the options of viewing the current variables as well as setting them... file generation is a breeze.  Unfortunately, by setting the date/time variable, it is locked to the value at the time of creation (naturally).  I set the variable like so:

```
UTCTIME=$(/bin/date --utc +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%Z")
```

What I really need is either a way to create a variable which updates at runtime, or (more likely) another way to skin this cat.

While scouring for solutions, I came across a similar issues... like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113548/how-to-define-a-auto-update-date-variable-in-bash).

But, to be honest, I'm stumped on how to marry the two approaches and create a simple, distributable solution.

.sh file is posted via pastebin, [here](http://pastebin.com/G7hic45J).

Comment: Please use proper capitalization and formatting on future posts; it makes things much easier to read.  And, when in doubt, it's always good to include your script with a pastebin link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function:

```
generate_filename() { echo "${1}_$(/bin/date --utc +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%Z")_$2"; }
```

And use it like this:

```
tcpdump -w "$(generate_filename foo tcpdump).lpc"
```

It's hard to get the function to automatically determine the command name. You can use bash history to get it and save a couple of characters typing:

```
tcpdump -w "$(generate_filename foo !#:0).lpc"
```

Comment: Yup.  That does the trick nicely.  Completely throws away the script I wrote and replaces it with a single, elegant snippet.  Thanks!